# List packages at "top" level?

Tags: vcpkg

I apologise if the title is misleading. What I mean is, if I installed boost (all of boost):

```
vcpkg install boost
```

along with other "smaller" packages such as openssl:

```
vcpkg install openssl
```

Now when I list the installed packages, is there a way to list only "boost" and "openssl"? Currently it shows ALL the packages within boost, when I only want to see the two.

Thanks.

Comment: Why you want to show only two? for the "eye" graphical use or  developing porpouses

Comment: I just want a compact way to see the packages I've installed. For example, openssl might get "lost" in all the boost stuff if I just list it. So primarily for the eye I guess. But it's more manageable too.

Comment: Can't help yu with this. Cause im in another platform ! Hope you solve it!